# Period before or after quotation mark?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, periods

If there is a quote at the end of a sentence, does the period of the quote go before or after the end quotation mark? And if the quote is ended by a question mark does it replace the period that would be at the end of the main sentence?

Comment: Here you're getting into serious House Style issues. Some like it one way, some like it the other. Form your own opinion of which way you want to go, for any reason you please, and follow it consistently, unless somebody is paying you enough money to do it the other way.

Comment: This custom varies from place to place.  If you are writing for publication, consult the style guidelines for that publisher/publication.  What I learned in school (in the US) for your questions: before, yes.